# Salesforce global popup based on user

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, global-actions

I know this is a loaded question but i'm curious if anyone can point me in the right direction. The ultimate goal is to try and create a task for inbound/outbound calls, and if salesforce is open, pop up a lighting component or form where user can view and enter additional details about the call.

But i know this is a big project so for now i am just wondering what my options are as to how i might translate this even to a popup component. I'm thinking i can create a platform event when an "in progress" task is created. From there i'm not sure how to push this event out to only the user this task is assigned to and i'm not sure how i can do this in a global environment (ie. the user doesn't have to take any action or open up any apps. Anywhere in salesforce this popup should happen).

Is it possible?

Comment: Are your users using a lightning console app?

Answer (score 2):

If you use CTI, you get this functionality "for free." It works both in Classic and Lightning. And if it isn't good enough, you can write your own [Open CTI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_intro.htm) connector to work in Classic and Lightning. The framework is already there, and there's vendors that already support this, so it's really just a matter of doing research.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to trigger this with an event without some sort of initialization on the users part. For example the examples here for importing the library https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_connecting.htm show this is an apex page. The apex page has to first be open no?

Comment: @BenArnao The Call Center defines how the system behaves; you don't need a VF page, but you do need a CTI server, which might be provided by a locally installed application (a CTI Adapter), or installed on a central server (this is the method we use internally). Those commands are sent to that server, which then manipulates the phone state, and can send commands back to Salesforce (e.g. when a call initiates), which then behaves according to the user's Call Center definition. The example you saw is only when you need support in a VF page to call commands.

Comment: Wouldn't the user still need to basically run this app first to get the functionality of responding to events?

Comment: @BenArnao no, CTI works as long as the user is logged in to Salesforce. The CTI part itself deals with responding to events.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way to trigger a global ui action like the call center does?

Comment: @BenArnao ... Maybe. I think you may need to be more specific in your question.